# Transposition of first matrix in crossprod in R

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a statistically important reason that the first matrix in `crossprod` is transposed? That is, why is `crossprod(x,y)` equivalent to `t(x) %*% y`, and not just to `x %*% y`?

Comment: If you are only asking about how R works, this question is off topic here. If you are asking about the mathematical nature of this operation, this Q is probably better asked on the [mathematics.SE] SE site. If there is a *statistical* (machine learning) motivation for this Q, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Sorry if I put it in a wrong place. I'm new to SE and it's structure is overhelming for me at the moment. I have crossprod in chi2 test so I thought that statistical forum is OK for my question.

Comment: Even if not focused on R, the question is still off-topic because it doesn't have a statistical background (you could easily edit it to make it comply though)

Comment: While I hope this question is edited to bring it more clearly within the scope of the site, the excellent answer by @Sycorax suggests that the question might actually belong here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because it assumes matrices dimensions $m\times n$ so you need to be multiplying $n\times m \cdot m \times n$ to yield a relevant matrix.

Comment: This reply only seems to restate the facts, without providing an answer to the "Why" of the question.

Answer (score 12):

As you indicated, `%*%` already does multiplication; there's not really a need for second function to do the same job. The function `crossprod` is a shortcut to transpose multiply, both in syntax and computation. For example, the normal equations $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ in R are `solve(crossprod(X), crossprod(X,y))`,* (single-argument `crossprod` computes $X^TX$). It's also faster than `solve(t(X)%*%X, t(X)%*%y)` because the second expression has to transpose and then multiply; this can be slow.

The normal equations are just a prominent example of the many, many occasions in statistics where transpose multiply is desired. It's exceptionally convenient to have access to have efficient access to that functionality.

*But you should not directly apply the normal equations for numerical reasons. Use `lm`, which applies the QR decomposition by default and is more robust to ill-conditioned matrices.

[This monograph](http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-MatrixAlgebra2010-pretty.pdf) defines crossproduct in a manner consistent with R's. (Herve Abdi, Lynne J. Williams. "Matrix Algebra." In Neil Salkind (Ed.), *Encyclopedia of Research Design.* Thousand Oaks, CA: Sage. 2010.)

Comment: I think you got the brackets wrong here?

Comment: ...or it's syntax I am not used to - the inverse, or solve in R, only applies to $X'X$, but apparently it also takes the other part of the linear system. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @ChristophHanck This is actually a subtlety to R. where `solve` gives the solution $x$ to $Ax=b$; if you don't provide a second argument, it assumes you're solving against the identity matrix, which corresponds to computing an explicit inverse to $A$. I'm not sure why, but most people only remember that `solve` computes an inverse, but not that it can solve a *specific* linear system.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should not post from a phone without testing the problem first.

Comment: I do not program in R, but I guess that another reason why `crossprod(X)` is faster than `t(X)%*%X` is because it knows that the result is symmetric and hence it can save about 50% of the work by only computing the upper triangle and then filling in the rest by symmetry.

Comment: @Federico That's a reasonable conjecture, borne out by timing tests.  Interestingly, some system monitoring indicates `crossprod` is not smart enough to perform the computation in place: it appears to allocate RAM for the transpose of `x`.

Comment: Is there some reason for the term "crossprod"? (I would think "dotprod" is more descriptive of the mathematical operation?)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I expanded my answer but R is so weird that I'm willing to chalk it up to general strangeness.

Comment: @whuber that is ... quite surprising. I wonder why it would be organized that way.